# Skipping Grades Music Theory

Tags: theory, abrsm

Is it possible to skip straight to Grade 5 Theory? Will be skipping to Grade 5 piano, and would like to continue to Grade 6 Piano.

Comment: Just to be clear, you should probably mention which exam board(s) you're talking about.

Comment: You can likely skip the exam, but don't skip the content.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine it's what a lot of folk do. I certainly did - take grade V theory as a passport to practical VI+. It's obvious that knowledge of the previous grades' content will be more than a bit important though.

It may well be dependent on the board used. In U.K. all of the exam boards require a grade V theory pass before continuing with practical above grade V, but it may not be so in other parts of the world and other boards.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that. It is not required of you to do grades from initial level up to grade 8 level, but in most cases it would be beneficial to you to do all the grades to equip yourself for the next grade. I have done grades 1 & 2 theory, years ago. I can't remember which grade I stopped at but I am continuing from next year with grades 4,5 and then 6 and perhaps up to grade 7 maybe, but I think if you go through Trinity College of London there is a entry level of grade three at least. Perhaps read the website and see what they say.

[Trinity College London](http://www.trinitycollege.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  I think you can even skip straight to Grade VIII theory if you want.   There's a Grade V theory requirement for higher-grade practical exams, but none for theory exams AFAIK.